# Default executioncontext with blocking calls

Tags: scala

I understand that using [blocking](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/concurrent/package.scala#L54) notifies the thread pool that the block of code you pass to it contains long-running or blocking operations. allowing the pool to temporarily spawn new workers to ensure starvation never happens. I use `blocking` blocks at some places but now thinking it may not be ideal to continue using `blocking` blocks with default executioncontext since there must be cost associated in creating temporary workers and then destroying them etc. Instead I could create a separate execution context to run blocking calls to avoid creation/destroying costs of worker threads but have enough pool size in a dedicated execution context. Or it's okay to use ONE executioncontext and continue using [blocking](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/concurrent/package.scala#L54) blocks?

Basically all the db calls are blocking and they are going be wrapped in `async{blocking{}}` (if continue using one ExecutionContext). There could be hundred or more DAO blocking APIs. And potentially thousands of users hitting the system.

Comment: It depends. Can you give us more information to work with? Numbers as to # of blocking calls run, or some other system level metrics to be better able to answer your question would be helpful.

Comment: @wheaties added some details. let me know if that's helpful.